# SD card "damaged" after every reboot / power off

Tags: boot, reboot, external-sd

When I turn off my phone, next time it says `SD card is damaged` and all data is gone, I can only reformat it. The phone is "gionee iq275" (also known as "Fly" in Russia), Android version is 2.3.4. What can be the source of problem? How can I get rid of it? I know, the phone is crap, but at the moment just throwing it away and buying another is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why that happened, but I got rid of the problem by making 2 things:

- Performed full format of the SD card, and
- Safely eject SD card before reboot of poweroff (not sure if it's necessary)

After that, I didn't see this problem again for now.

## Update

That crappy phone sometimes damages SD card content regardless of whether the techniques written above are used... it seems to be a device-specific problem. So, my advice (if anyone else reads this) - don't buy "no-name" Chinese phones! :D

Comment: This is a problem for Samsung phones and Moto Gs as far as I have seen, so it's not restricted to certain brands. Format & safe eject does not work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer, in case someone else is having similar problem, even after a decade of original answer to question.

One way of early prevention is, format SD card into exFAT. I never used my sd card as "internal" or RAM extension, so your usage could be different. exFAT SD cards no longer have issues, whenever my phone reboots(due to update or whatever reason).

I faced this issue in Nokia and Xiaomi devices, so I put blames on Android OS way of handling external SD cards(From Android 9.0 to 14.0).

In case of recovery, easeus recovery tool has SD card option, but not free/freemium.